# Excel pie chart for one column?

Tags: excel

Not sure how frequently excel questions are asked here, but I'm trying to get a pie chart generated for one column of different information, that would display the data in terms of what the visual representation is. For ex
Column B titled "food"
Different possible entries for the column are
Apple
Bread
Corn
Pizza.

I'd like to insert pie chart that shows the visual distribution of how many times there was pizza entered, and corn, and for the others.

Thoughts on formula to do this?
Thanks. -wilson

Comment: Do you need it to be one column? You could (and would likely be better off) putting each unique food type in its own column, and doing a `COUNTIF()`  on that, then making the chart from there.

Comment: Afraid not. This is from a client .data file automatically being sent. It's how it's designed basically

Comment: You can create a pivot table from the one column, then from that a pivot chart.

Comment: I've been looking into pivot tables. An issue I have though, is that my data is displayed like this. I don't know how to deal with it. Any thoughts? https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/34011190424/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: That data would fit into a pivot table.  Put the Column in both rows and calc.  then do a Pivot chart.

Comment: Hm doesn't seem to let me do both. Everytime I try to swap it over, it removes it from either row or columns

Comment: this belongs on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that many data points, the chart should be a horizontal bar, not a pie. Pie charts are too hard to interpret.

Create a pivot chart, pull the Shape field into the Axis (Categories) area and again into the Values area.
[image]